# How to use dotnet (.NET Core) to pack a sln file that contains a sql project?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have a nothing-special .NET Core solution, lets call it `Application.sln`, and it contains 12 C# projects, and 1 SQL project. In Visual Studio 2017, I have no issue building all the projects, but when I head to the command line to package up the projects using `dotnet pack Application.sln --no-build`, I immediately run into an issue with the sql project. Here is the error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
```

After deciphering that, I found out that the first part, `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0` comes from me using dotnet instead of msbuild to package up the solution, and since SSDT cannot be installed into the dotnet folder, this will fail.

Preferably, I would like it to ignore the .sqlproj project and only pack the .csproj projects as I will be handling the sql projects separately afterwards, but I do not see any way to do that. Is there a way? It does not appear that I can use MSBuild style wild cards as a parameter to `dotnet pack` (***.csproj) as that throws a separate error.

I have tried using msbuild /t:pack but that gives me other issues (it says the target "pack" does not exist in the project).

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? If it helps, I am wanting to do this through TeamCity, but all of these issues exist on my development machine as well.

Comment: Can you unload the SQL project?

Comment: I could, but the ultimate goal is to run in a CI environment, and that would not be a workable solution, I do not think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if you want to use the `dotnet` tools, you will need to create a second solution that contains only the c# projects. If you don't want to do this, you can always use the msbuild commands directly from the VS 2017 developer command prompt (`dotnet restore`=> `msbuild /t:Restore` etc.)

The `Pack` target is only available for projects with integrated NuGet package support, which comes through using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` SDK ("new" csproj format) or using the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` nuget package in projects that are compatible with it.

If you want to call `dotnet pack` / `msbuild /t:Pack` on a solution without creating a second solution without the sql projects, all projects must contain a pack target.

An easy way to do that is to create a `Directory.Build.props` file next to the solution with the following contents:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Pack" />
</Project>
```

This file will be automatically imported at the beginning of all projects in the directory hierarchy and define an empty `Pack` target in them. Projects using the .NET SDK will then overwrite this target with the actual NuGet pack targets. So `msbuild /t:Pack` will call this empty target on the SQL project and the original NuGet `Pack` target on the c# projects.

Comment: In the end, I had to resort to using 2 slns, which was not my preferred way to solve this issue. I tried the other fix you suggested, but that never seemed to work in TeamCity. Thanks for helping confirm that two slns was the only way to get the desired behavior.

Comment: interesting. the workaround should have worked as long as there are no other `Directory.Build.props` files around but I tried it only from the command line, not form a CI setup.

Comment: fyi you can also use an msbuild script to perform all the necessary task and not rely too much on configuring commands.. https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/69f5303aa79a8cd4060e44891c90fd2d

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will probably reference this question again later as we mature with .NET Core, but in the meantime, I actually found a rather nice solution using OctoPack (the whole reason for packaging in the first place was for TeamCity to package up projects for OctopusDeploy to deploy) as it handled .sqlprojs with no issue. Thanks again though!